Playwright Component testing requires the use of the defineConfig()
I'm using playwright in order to run tests on my components.
I've installed playwright using this command:
npm init playwright@latest -- --ct 

Here's my playywright-ct config file:
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/experimental-ct-react';
export default defineConfig({
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'setup',
      testMatch: /global.setup\.ts/,
    },
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: devices['Desktop Chrome'],
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },
    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: devices['Desktop Firefox'],
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },
    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: devices['Desktop Safari'],
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },
  ],
});

Also, this is my Button component:
import * as React from 'react';
import { cn } from '../../../lib/utils';
import IconWrapper from '../Icon/Icon';
import { IconType } from 'react-icons';

export type ButtonProps = React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & {
  Icon?: IconType;
  label?: string;
  backgroundColor?: string;
  className?: string;
  dir?: 'ltr' | 'rtl';
};

const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  (
    { className, Icon, label, backgroundColor = 'bg-primary-dark-green', dir = 'rtl', ...props },
    ref,
  ) => {
    return (
      <button
        className={cn(
          'font-medium flex cursor-pointer items-center justify-center gap-3 rounded-full py-2 text-center text-text-white transition-opacity duration-300 ease-in-out hover:opacity-80',
          Icon && label === undefined ? 'p-2' : 'px-4',
          backgroundColor,
          `${props.disabled ? 'opacity-50 hover:cursor-default hover:opacity-50' : ''}`,
          className,
        )}
        dir={dir}
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
      >
        {Icon && <IconWrapper IconComponent={Icon} data-testid="button-icon" />}
        {label ? label : null}
      </button>
    );
  },
);

Button.displayName = 'Button';

export default Button;

And this is my test:
import React from 'react';
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/experimental-ct-react';
import Button from '.';

test.describe('Button Component', () => {
  test('should render with label', async ({ mount }) => {
    const component = await mount(<Button label="Button Test" />);
    await expect(component).toContainText('Button Test');
  });
});

I'm having an error whenever I'm running my test using npx playwright test.
Error is:
Error: Component testing requires the use of the defineConfig() in your playwright-ct.config.{ts,js}: https://aka.ms/playwright/ct-define-config

Tried to follow their documentation but it didn't help, tests are still failing.

Where are the setting which are mentioned here ? I guess your config is insufficient.

@KlimBim i've mentioned them above, in the second code snippet
export default defineConfig...

Did you try to run npm run test-ct instead of npx playwright test ?
